# Is it grammatical to say "according to the law" instead of "according the law"?

Tags: meaning, prepositions

Is it grammatical to say "according to the law" instead of "according the law"?

If so, is there any difference in meaning?

Comment: I believe you want to ask if it is "grammatically correct" to say... I don't think "is it grammatical to say" carries the right meaning.

Comment: @MuhammadbinYusrat yes it does, actually. Something [can be *grammatical* or not](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/grammatical). It's an adjective, just like any other.

Comment: It would be better if you could show a complete example sentence - a few words out of context can be very ambiguous in English!

Comment: To illustrate how important the example sentence is, suppose you had incorrectly extracted this phrase from its context as suggested in one of the answers below? You would then be told the wrong meaning of what you had read. In such cases not only do you need an example sentence, it must be _the same_ sentence in which you encountered the sequence of words.

Comment: The question definitely needs some context; that is, was there some particular text where "according the law" was used?

Comment: Did you mean to say "according to law" instead of "according the law"?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

When an average person hears the words *according* and *law*, the first thing that probably comes to their mind is the expression *according to the law*. So, no, ***according the law*** is incorrect. You should always say ***according to the law***. [***according to something***](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/according-to) is actually a set phrase in English and you just can't leave the ***to*** out from it. It's part of the expression and therefore it must be there. Nor can you say ***according of the law***. Again, that's just incorrect grammar.

However, *according the law* would still be grammatically correct, but it would mean a completely different thing. In this case, *according* is the present participle of the verb *to accord* which means to give or grant something to someone. For example:

> **Accord the law the necessary status** in society is a task of the highest priority if we are to build a fair and just legal system.

Comment: But it's "regarding the law", not "regarding to it"

Comment: I'm totally with you on that.

Comment: We don't always say "according to the law"; sometimes we say "according to law".

Comment: I'm afraid this answer is incorrect.  mcalex has given a fine example of the words "according the law" used properly.

Comment: I think I've heard "according to law" once or twice, but I don't think this is a common phrasing. It might be British though.

Comment: Actually, the ngrams say that "according to law" is more common in US English than UK English.  But either way, the question was about "according the law", which is far less common than either "according to law"  or "according to the law".  Of course, all three are perfectly grammatical (and yes, I am a native speaker of English).

Comment: On the very reasonable assumption that the questioner thinks "according the law" means the same as 'according to the law" (which it doesn't) this is a good answer.

Comment: Well, if there is not enough context, you have to make assumptions. As you aptly pointed out, it's very reasonable to assume that the OP thinks that "according to the law" might possibly be made shorter by tossing out the "to".

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem A possible reason "according to law" would rank higher could be that it lends itself to more phrases, such as "according to law professionals," "according to law books," "according to law theory."  Furthermore, I would consider both of those to be valid usages, but with slight differences that render them subtly more or less appropriate, based on the context.  The question here is more about "according to (noun with or without article)" versus "according (noun with or without article)."  Obviously, the latter is incorrect in all scenarios.

Comment: "according the law is completely incorrect": no, it is not.  See [mcalex's answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/147355/20035).

Comment: "According the law" would be correct in some constructions, e.g. "While I favor according the law a great deal of deference, this decision is unjust." That's unlikely to be what the asker was looking for, but there also isn't any context.

Answer (score 73):

In the usual context of these words, as others have pointed out, one invariably says 'according **to** the law'.

However, you **can** use 'according the law', just not in the context you're referring to.  To illustrate:

> In areas of open lawlessness, according the law the respect it deserves can be difficult, if not impossible to achieve.

This obviously uses 'according' as a verb, not a preposition as in the example sentences.

I mention this usage as I don't think "No, according the law is completely incorrect," or "Only “according to the law” is correct" are entirely correct.

Kevin notes: This usage is dated and seldom used anymore.

Comment: This seems a stretch to me; yes, the words are in the order specified in the question, but "according the law" is not a phrase in this sentence, only "according X the respect it deserves", with X substituted for "the law". There are many coincidences of word order like this, and if this quote was in the question, the answer would *still* be that "according the law" is not a grammatical phrase, and the sentence has been parsed wrong if that "phrase" was picked out.

Comment: @IMSoP Possibly, but we have no context within which to make that kind of judgment. It's very possible that the OP saw the phrase 'according the law', and parsed it incorrectly, hence the confusion.

Comment: Should note too that, in this case (when it's being used as a verb), I would say that "according to the law" is also correct *i.e.* "according to the law the respect it deserves". That answers the original question.

Comment: Let's give the OP the benefit of the doubt. Most likely s/he heard or saw the words "according the law" as part of a phrase and also later saw or heard the phrase "according to the law" and wondered why the need for those pesky two letters in the latter case. I'm giving the OP the benefit of the doubt in guessing s/he didn't think "according the law" was a phrase at all but a not-entirely-uncommon sequence of words.

Comment: @IMSoP For native or highly skilled speakers, the difference between the two cases is clear, but to those with less mastery, it can be a lot harder to distinguish between two cases that use the same words but with different meanings. I'd say the best answer in this case would mention both cases.

Comment: Downvote because you are using the wrong word.  You _afford_ something the respect it deserves, not _accord_.

Comment: @Kevin - You can also use accord as a transitive verb, meaning "give" or "grant," but it's very uncommon and will no doubt be far less common than usages of "according to (something)."

Comment: @bubbleking That usage is extremely dated

Comment: @Kevin - That may be, but now that multiple users have mentioned it, I don't think it's appropriate to insist that mcalex is "using the wrong word" or to downvote for it.  I hadn't heard the usage before finding this discussion, but I've been convinced that it does, in fact, have a legitimate, albeit rare, existence.  If I had delivered a downvote for it, and then read the supporting evidence, I would be compelled to remove my downvote.

Comment: @bubbleking if the was the English Language exchange, I would agree with you.  But since this is for _Learners_, I think suggesting something that would get them strange looks from most people is not a good idea. Especially without mentioning that it is a dated and very uncommon usage

Comment: @Kevin It's not extremely dated, but it is obscure. But do you know where it *is* used? Ironically enough, it's a phrase you'd most likely come across in contracts and law!

Comment: Just to add to the confusion, you could use *according to the law the respect it deserves* to give the same meaning as *according the law the respect it deserves*. But you can't use *according the law I have the right to unicorns* to give the same meaning as *according to the law I have the right to unicorns*.

Comment: @nekomatic It helps to clear the confusion a little to note that your first phrase changes the indirect object of the participle _according_ (in the second phrase) to an object of a preposition, following the method that indirect objects can be rephrased as a _to_ / _for_ prepositional phrase. In both cases, the word _according_ could be replaced with the synonymous _giving_ or _granting_.

Comment: @Kevin Absolutely not. _Accord_ and _afford_ mean **completely different things**. This is not by any stretch of the imagination “using the wrong word”. _Afford someone respect_ barely even makes sense—and it is also [about **ten times** rarer](http://bit.ly/2zg1n8j) than _accord someone respect_.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet   One of the definitions of afford is _to give or confer upon_. That _specific_ usage (with _respect_)  might be more common, but generally speaking [https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=accord+_PRON_+respect%2Cafford+_PRON_+respect%2Caccord+_PRON_++_NOUN_%2Cafford+_PRON_+_NOUN_&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Caccord%20_PRON_%20respect%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cafford%20_PRON_%20respect%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Caccord%20_PRON_%20_NOUN_%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cafford%20_PRON_%20_NOUN_%3B%2Cc0](the opposite is true)

Answer (score 14):

"**[According to](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/according_to)**" is a set phrase in English to indicate where something is specified.  You can't just drop the "to" and expect it to have the same meaning.

The verb *[to accord](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/accord#Verb)* has a number of meanings; the only sense in which it could abut a noun phrase like that is as a transitive verb; example: "I was according the law the respect it deserves".  That's unlikely to be the sense intended here.

Comment: Surely (per your second paragraph) you mean that you can't drop a word and expect the phrase to have *the same* meaning, not that you can't expect it to have *any* meaning, right?

Comment: Good point, @Kyle - fixed.

Answer (score 5):

“According the law” is ungrammatical. Only “according to the law” is correct.

Comment: Do some say "according of the law"?

Comment: Nope! You can say “in accordance with the law”, however.

Comment: Well, all you said seems to be totally the same as in Russian so far, except some uneducated people in Russia may say "according of the law" (this is still ungrammatical).

Comment: Well, you have to understand that Russian and English are two quite different languages. So, I wouldn't draw parallels between them.

Comment: We can also say "according to law".  So it's not quite right to say that "only 'according to the law' is correct" - though I suppose you mean "out of these two options".

Comment: I'm afraid this is incorrect, as mcalex's answer has demonstrated.

Answer (score 1):

"According to" is certainly far more common in current usage.  I cannot imagine dropping the "to" except perhaps in some unusual, perhaps archaic, construction.

[OED](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/according) lists *according* as an adverb and notes that it's "usually" *according to*.  They also list a second sense as *according as*.

[M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/according%20to) and [Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/according-to) list *according to* as a preposition.

Comment: It's quite common in Indian English, along with "refer the documentation" and "due unforeseen circumstances".

Comment: @Lightness Such variations are bound to arise in pidgin-like variants. I had a philology teacher once who was forever admonishing us not to trust critical editions of manuscripts themselves, but to “always take a look the original”.